# Angular 6 environment for API URL passing client url also

Tags: angular, angular6, mean-stack

For the Mean stack, I setup environment for apiUrl in angular 6 as below

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http:localhost:3000'
};
```

And i have included that in service.ts

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

const API_URL= environment.apiUrl;

login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(API_URL + '/api/auth/login', { username: username, password: password })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }

            return user;
        }));
}
```

But when the login request sent. It takes angular base url as well.

```
POST http://localhost:4200/localhost:3000/api/auth/login 404 (Not Found)
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Can you please share the login request code as well

Comment: added login request code

Comment: did you try adding '//' before http:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like URL configuration code is not correct ('//' after 'http:' is missing).

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
};
```